# Blackberry submission process, need to get app up

Tags: blackberry

I really need to get my app up as soon as possible, however there are some issues with the app working the way I want in os 5.0 but works great in os6+

I'm just wondering if I submit it would just be turned down. I want to get it up, and while that is happening I can be preparing an update. Same with resolution support, I may need to increase the amount of phones I reach, but right now there is no time. What I'm asking is will rim not accept an app because it's just not compatible with all phones?

Also, should I building separate cod files for different os compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app works well in os6.0 + and not so well in Os 5.0 ,submit the app and set the MinOS (minimum OS version compatible with the File Bundle) to OS6.0 . so the app wont be visible to os 5.0 users. It will only be visible to os 6.0 users. Once you upload, you can then work on it and then for the next release, update the file bundle with min os set to OS5.0

Its upto your discretion to set the number of devices/os/carrier/language, your app supports. Even if its just one device, RIM will accept the app. Make sure the app is signed, and it doesnt do anything crazy.